# convert matrix to symbol in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a 100000x8 matrix and I need to convert each row to some symbolic representation.
I have this working without problems but do to the size of my matrix I'd like to vectorize the solution.

Here is what I have working:

```
cutoff = [-inf -1.15 -0.67 -0.32 0 0.32 0.67 1.15];
 for k = 1 : length(matrix)
  tmp = matrix(k,:);
  for i = 1 : length(tmp)    
    string(i) = sum( (cutoff <= tmp(i)), 2 );
  end
 end
```

So for example if line 1 of my matrix is 0.1053    0.1053    0.1053    0.1053    0.0737   -0.0308   -0.0034    0.0353 I get string = 5     4     6     3     4     5     5     5.
Any help would be much appreciated,
Thanks for your time.

Comment: What is the problem here?

Comment: I need to avoid the for loops.

Comment: So the title should be "can I vectorize this operation" or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To vectorize the solution, you can use `bsxfun` combined with a reshape

```
string = sum(bsxfun(@ge,matrix,reshape(cutoff,1,1,[])),3);
```

`cutoff` is turned into a 1-by-1-by-3 array, so that the sum is taken for every element.

BTW: You may want to avoid `length` on an array of unknown number of rows: If the number of rows is smaller than the number of columns, `length` will return the number of columns. Use `size(matrix,1)` for the number of rows, instead.

Comment: Thanks. That's the place I am stuck. The result is not quite what i need. I get the sum for each row and not for each element as in the example. I need to get a result the same size as the matrix (100000x8).

Comment: Yep. That does it. Wonderful. Thank you so much... (I actually nearly nailed it, but the reshape always seems to elude me somehow) Thanks again.